# Overflow:auto doesn't display horizontal scrollbar

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a gridview that has some 20 columns and 1000 rows. The grid is placed under `<div>` tag. Due to such large figures, the div shows the vertical scrollbars, which is fine but it doesn't show the horizontal scrollbar.

The css written for div is as;

```
.divCSS{
display:block;
position:relative;
width: auto;
height: 5em;
margin:0;
padding:5px;
background:inherit;
color:inherit;
overflow:auto;
}
```

The entire `<div>` code is as below;

```
<div id="divGrid" align="left" style="border: solid 1px gray; width: 790px; height: 420px;" class="divCSS">
```

Despite giving overflow:auto, why i don't see a horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: Maybe if you give the grid view a width that's larger than 790 pixels...

Comment: Dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a fixed width and have set your `overflow` to the value `auto` then, to quote the W3C:

> The behavior of the 'auto' value is user agent-dependent, but should
> cause a scrolling mechanism to be provided for overflowing boxes.

In other words, your scroll behaviour may vary depending on the browser. Given you've defined both a fixed height and width, your browser will wrap your text so that it doesn't impact adjacent elements and does the minimum to ensure it merely supports a visible scrolling mechanism to display such that users could access the clipped content.

If you want to see the horizontal scroll bars, you need to include content length that cannot wrap and exceeds your specified element width, such as an image or by specifying `white-space: nowrap` on one of your contained elements (e.g. a paragraph).

Have a look at [this example](http://jsbin.com/ayatuq) for an illustration of how it works.

Answer (score 2):

Give the width of the div specific and set `overflow-x:visible;`

Answer (score 1):

REmove

```
width: auto;
height: 5em;
```

from your divCSS class

and for scroll to apper you need content width more than 790px and hight more than 420px.

Answer (score 1):

try 
`{
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:scroll;
}`